# Performing an upsert operation on MySQL using Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I have a table with around 700 records; I'm trying to create a Python script which should update this table, so every record must be updated with a new value. If the Python script finds a new record that was not on the table previously, it should add it to my table (**upsert**).

Here is what I tried:

```
for x in mydatadict:
    y = x.replace("/", "-")
    z = x.replace("/", "")
    sql = "INSERT INTO my_table (first, second, third) VALUES(%s, %s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE first=%s"
    val = (y, z, x, y)
    cursor.execute(sql, val)

db.commit()
```

The problem with my actual code is that it won't update the record but will only insert them. So if I had 700 records, after running this script I will have 1400 records. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So which column is set to be unique so mysql knows this new one is a duplicate? In other words which column is the DUPLICATED KEY

Comment: It should be the column 'first'!

Comment: But is it, can we see the schema for that table

Comment: It's very simple, there are only those three columns

Comment: Yes ..... but only if the table is defined correctly will there be any way for mysql to realise that a duplicate is being created. Just do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` and copy/paste the output to your question

Comment: Otherwise we have to assume you have not created a unique column in this table and therefore mysql is quite happy to create as many rows as you like with exactly that same value in the column named `first`

Comment: Ok, i'm sorry for the delay; i think the problem might be, indeed, that 'first' is not a primary key, let me make some check

Comment: That was the problem, indeed, my bad for being negligent on this; is there anyway to reward you?

Answer (score 1):

If the `first` column is truly the primary key, and you essentially want to ignore duplicate rows (since your `ON DUPLICATE KEY` just sets that column to the same inserted value), then you can use `INSERT IGNORE INTO...` which will stop it from raising errors. You don't need an `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause either for that.

> ...if you use the INSERT IGNORE statement, the rows with invalid data
>   that cause the error are ignored and the rows with valid data are
>   inserted into the table

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-ignore/